# Gerar HTML final em PHP ou em JS?

Tags: php, javascript, desempenho

Qual é a melhor forma, a melhor performance, de gerar o HTML final. Direto em *server-side* ou receber os dados do banco e gerar o HTML em *client-side*?

No desenvolvimento de minha aplicação atual, me deparei com essa dúvida, por receber os dados do servidor e depois gerar grande parte do HTML em JavaScript.

Comment: Depende, a grosso modo, se o HTML a que você se refere é toda a página, vale mais a pena gerar no servidor, agora se você precisar atualizar somente uma parte da página após esta ter carregado, é menos custoso atualizar somente a parte necessária via AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gere do lado do servidor. É mais fácil confiar que o servidor é rápido do que confiar na rapidez do computador do cliente.

O computador do cliente pode ser antigo, ter pouca memória ou otras limitações que você não sabe. Se um outro script na página falhar a sua página pode ficar parada.

Outro aspeto a ter em conta é o SEO. Se o site não têm conteúdo sem correr JS então o conteúdo indexado pelos motores de busca vai ser mais pobre.

Answer (score 0):

Depende muito da sua necessidade e do tipo de aplicação que você está criando.

Eu, na geração de conteúdo, usaria muito ajax se minha aplicação fosse uma área restrita e que não precisasse indexar este conteúdo no google, por exemplo.